# How do I add a SOAP Header using Java JAX-WS

Tags: soap, header, jax-ws

A typical SOAP client request using JAX-WS might be

```
FooService service = new FooService();
FooPort port = service.getFooPort();
FooPayload payload = new FooPayload();
payload.setHatSize(3);
payload.setAlias("The Hat");
...
port.processRequest(payload);
```

This generates an HTTP request content something like

```
<?xml ... ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://...soap-envelope">
  <S:Body>
    <!-- payload -->
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

By manipulating the arguments to the port.processRequest() call you can only affect the "payload" part. You can't affect the outer part of the XML message.

I want to insert a SOAP header just before the SOAP Body

```
<S:Header>
   <X:Security xmlns:X="http://...wsssecurity...>
      <X:BinarySecurityToken>kjh...897=</X:BinarySecurityToken>
   </X:Security>
</S:Header>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Does the WSDL describe the headers? If so, then doesn't JAX-WS generate the code to add them?

Answer (score 19):

Thanks Nuno,

Just as soon as I work out how to log in properly to stackoverflow.com I'll do the right thing with your reply.

In the mean time here's the code I ended up with:

```
FooService service = new FooService();
service.setHandlerResolver(new HandlerResolver() {
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
        List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
        handlerList.add(new RGBSOAPHandler());
        return handlerList;
    }
});
FooPort port = service.getFooPort();
FooPayload payload = new FooPayload();
payload.setHatSize(3);
payload.setAlias("The Hat");
...
port.processRequest(payload);
```

and

```
class RGBSOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return new TreeSet();
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        Boolean outboundProperty = 
            (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
            try {
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage()
                        .getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
                String prefix = "X";
                String uri = "http://...wsssecurity...";
                SOAPElement securityElem = 
                        factory.createElement("Security",prefix,uri);
                SOAPElement tokenElem = 
                        factory.createElement("BinarySecurityToken",prefix,uri);
                tokenElem.addTextNode("kjh...897=");
                securityElem.addChildElement(tokenElem);
                SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();
                header.addChildElement(securityElem);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in handler: " + e);
            }
        } else {
            // inbound
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm taking the same exact steps as you, but I'm getting the following exception: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. Have you encountered this issue? The app is running on weblogic 10.1

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at handlers and handler chains.- I recently had to add a cookie to a given Webservice call and that was how i did it, just created a handler that intercepted the initial call and injected the cookie, you can also manipulate the call headers with a Pivot Handler

Answer (score 0):

for add Soap header, if you implement the WS on the web application server, the Was will add security part at header , after you have configure as per WS-SECURITY standard , such as web-policy etc. I don't understand why need add yourself except the encrypted content part , such as encrypted password etc