# How to authenticate a Web Service Client with JAX-WS / SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to web service and tried some tutorials. But I stumble on patrol when I try to access a HTTPS secure SOAP web service. I can access the `WSDL` with my browser and Netbeans with a login/password that I have revived from the provider.

Netbeans generate service/schema classes (via authentication) and I run my client on Glassfish 3.1.2. I have added a Servlet to access the Service. But I get a HTTP response code: 401 (=Unauthorized) when trying to access the service and `WSDL`. The service do connects to `HTTPS`, but the error tells `HTTP`.

What is the correct way to add the username/password to access a Web Service ?

Service provider for the Servlet

```
private static LogicalModel pullpullEnterpriseService() {
    pullEnterpriseService service = new pullEnterpriseService();        
    ClientPullSoapBinding port = service.getClientPullSoapBinding();        

    BindingProvider prov = ((BindingProvider)port);
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myuser");
    prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypassword");

    return port.getDataModel();
}
```

I tried with providing user/password in the SOAP header to, but with the same result

```
    ...
    Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();        

    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("myuser"));
    headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("mypassword"));
    req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
    ...
```

I have looked at these post, but they do not solve my problem:

[How do I add a SOAP Header using Java JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830691/how-do-i-add-a-soap-header-using-java-jax-ws?rq=1)

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Storing the WSDL Locally in your project.

See an example in [Consuming a Web Service with Java 6 and JAX-WS - Wiki - Confluence](https://web.archive.org/web/20111228034036/shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Consuming+a+Web+Service+with+Java+6+and+JAX-WS).

Then you can use the way in the *Specifying the Endpoint Address and HTTP Basic Authorization* section, like your first code in your question.

I hope this help you.

Comment: That worked, but now I have to manually check if the WSDL change. In case I get runtime error when the schema change.

Comment: [Link](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Consuming+a+Web+Service+with+Java+6+and+JAX-WS) in the answer is dead now.

Comment: Replaced the link with archive.org backup. Note: code snippets will not display, but are still available in the CDATA sections of the html source.